# Golang migrate installation failing on Ubuntu 22.04 with the following GPG error public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY B53DC80D13EDEF05

Tags: go, ubuntu-22.04, golang-migrate

I am trying to install Golang Migrate on Ubutu 22.4 and I get the following error while trying to execute the commands.

*Error public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY B53DC80D13EDEF05*

This is what I have tried so far, and it throws the Public Key not found message while trying to execute the 2nd command - sudo-apt-get update.

1.

```
curl -s https://packagecloud.io/install/repositories/golang-migrate/migrate/script.deb.sh | sudo bash
```

2. sudo apt-get update
3. 

```
sudo apt-get install migrate
```

I have tried to add the keys manually using the following command but still its showing the same error while executing sudo apt-get update.

```
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys B53DC80D13EDEF05
```

The above 3 commands works fine on Ubuntu 20.4 but not on 22.4. Any leads or solutions will be highly helpful.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes its a great pleasure to find the solution even after so many trial and error methods, a simple one liner command line script has resolved the issue,

```
curl https://packages.cloud.google.com/apt/doc/apt-key.gpg | sudo apt-key --keyring /usr/share/keyrings/cloud.google.gpg add -
```

After Executing this I have installed Go Migrate using the following commands.

```
curl -s https://packagecloud.io/install/repositories/golang-migrate/migrate/script.deb.sh | sudo bash
    
    
sudo apt-get update

    
    
sudo apt-get install migrate
```